# DomPDF não carrega informações

Tags: symfony-2, dompdf, php-5

Estou usando PHP 5.4.43 numa aplicação Symfony 2.3.36 e o meu PDF está vindo em branco.
Solicitacaopdf.html.twig

## Teste 1

SolicitacaoController.php

```
/**
 * @Route("/solicitacaopdf")
 */
public function solicitacaopdfAction()
{
    // CONFIGURANDO O DomPDF
    // Configure o Dompdf de acordo com suas necessidades
    $pdfOptions = new Options();
    $pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Arial');

    // GERANDO O PDF DO HTML
    $dompdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);

    // ISSO VAI SUBIR, ENTRAR NO LUGAR DO HTML POSTERIORMENTE
    // Recupere o HTML gerado em nosso arquivo twig
    $html = $this->renderView("LabBundle::Solicitacao/solicitacaopdf.html.twig", array(
        'title' => "e-SUS Laboratório"
    ));

    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
   // $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    // Renderizar o HTML como PDF
    $saidaPdf = $dompdf->output();

    // ENVIANDO O PDF. POSSA SER QUE PRECISE MUDAR ALGUMAS COISAS PARA FAZER DOWNLOAD. MAS O BÁSICO É ISSO AQUI
    $response = new Response($saidaPdf);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    return $response;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou sabendo como resolver.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido adicionando:

```
$dompdf->render();
```

Antes de:

```
$saidaPdf = $dompdf->output();
```